# Want to submit data using input in field & pressing "Enter" but not using any button(Data are passing through ajax)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ascii

```
<html><input id="test" type="text" /></html>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#test").keypress(function(event)
        {
            if ((event.charCode == 32) || (event.charCode == 64))
                alert("Working with space & @ but not with Enter");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my code but it's not working for ascii of 'Enter' which is '13'

Answer (score 0):

You can use "event.which" instead of "event.charCode" to get the key pressed.
event.which will return 13 for enter key pressed.

Example:

```
var code = event.charCode || event.which;
 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
 }
```